# Is there a way to use two classes on one element or emulate this behavior?

Tags: css

I need to do:

```
  <p id="un_but" class="blue_but" class="radius_right">SignUp</p>
```

but this does not work.

Obviously I could just combine the class properties but I was wondering if there is another way perhaps

Comment: `class="blue_but radius_right"` is how you do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
  <p id="un_but" class="blue_but radius_right" >SignUp</p>
```

dom element(`p`) can have only ONE attribute(`class`), but with multiple values separated by space

Answer (score 1):

One of the lesser known tricks with CSS is the fact that you don't have to limit your elements to just one class. If you need to set multiple classes on an element, you add them simply by separating them with a space in your attribute. For example:

```
<p class="pullquote btmmargin left">...</p>
```

This sets the following three classes on that paragraph tag:

pullquote
btmmargin
left
You would assign these as generic classes in your CSS:

```
.pullquote { ... }
 .btmmargin { ... }
 p.left { ... }
```

If you set the class to a specific element, you can still use it as part of a list of classes, but be aware that it will only affect those elements that are specified in the CSS.

You can use the important keyword to set precedence over different classes. 
For example:

```
.pullquote { width :15 px !important }
     .btmmargin { width:20px  }
     p.left { ... }
```

In the example above 20px width attribute will have more precedence.